# kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk without IAT

Tags: windows, dll, iat

On starting `notepad.exe` with Ollydbg, I see that `eax` has a value that points at `kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk`.

`notepad.exe` does not seem to import `kernel32.dll::BaseThreadInitThunk`.
I cannot find that function, by running dependency walker on `notepad.exe`.

How can `kernel32.dll::BaseThreadInitThunk` function be executed without importing it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a coincidence. It happens sometimes that the value in a register be the address of some valid api which the application has nothing to do about. For reference see these images.

I have loaded OllyDbg2 in OllyDbg2. OllyDbg2 does not import `kernel32.dll::BaseThreadInitThunk`

[image: In Windows 7]
**Ollydbg in Windows 7**

[image: In Windows XP]
**Ollydbg in Windows XP**

In Windows 7 on entrypoint the value of `eax` is the address of `BaseThreadInitThunk`. However on Windows XP the value of `eax` is 0.

Comment: starting eax value may be meaningless. thank you.

Comment: FYI, it can be used to help identify the host operating system. Not too useful in general, other than for potentially identifying emulators. https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/InitialValues